# a function that consumes a decimal and returns it in unary

Tags: scheme, racket

I am designing a function that consumes a natural number (like 0, 1, 2, ....etc) and returns the string representing it in unary (base 1) using the symbol I and also displaying the number in decimal after its unary form. So if I type in 2, I would get `"II (2)"`.  5, I would get `"IIIII (5)"` .

I've done it this way:

```
  (define (number->unary c )
      (cond
       [(= c  1 )  "I (1)" ]
       [(= c  2 ) "II (2)" ]
       [(= c  3) "III (3)"]
       [(= c  4) "IIII (4)"]
       [(= c  5) "IIIII (5)"]
       [(= c  6) "IIIIII (6)"]
       [(= c  7) "IIIIIII (7)"]
       [(= c  8) "IIIIIIII (8)"]
       [(= c  9) "IIIIIIIII (9)"]
       [(= c  10) "IIIIIIIIII (10)"]))
```

but is there an easier way to do this problem? I've been reading about number->string, string-appends, and replicates but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier way indeed - using a loop for generating the appropriate number of `"I"` characters. Think of it, what would happen if `c` equals `100`? you shouldn't have to create a hundred conditions for this!

Here's one possible way, using a helper procedure for implementing iteration with a recursive procedure called `loop`:

```
(define (number->unary c)
  (loop c (string-append " (" (number->string c) ")")))

(define (loop num str)
  (if (zero? num)
      str
      (loop (sub1 num) (string-append "I" str))))
```

Comment: @Josh what teaching language are you using? at least, can you use recursive procedures?

Comment: I am using beginning student.

Comment: the below says it expects only one  expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part.

Answer (score 0):

This works in the Beginning Student language.

The following produces the unary part.

```
(define (number->unary c )
  (cond
    [(= c 0) ""]
    [else    (string-append "I" (number->unary (- c 1)))]))
```

The append the counter afterwards (are you sure the parenthesis 
is meant to be in the output?).